# Passing in a list of items (that can possibly be null) as params for an IN clause using Dapper

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dapper

I am getting a NULL Reference Exception when trying to pass a NULL list of items as a parameter using Dapper. Normally in my where clause I would simply do the following:

```
"AND (@Sections IS NULL OR Section IN @Sections)";
```

But I am unable to do this because it won't work even when there are items in the sections list. Dapper adds them as parameters and (@sections1,@sections2 IS NULL OR) will error out. If I leave my sections list null because I don't want to use it as a filter I get a NULL reference exception.

My function must have a list of sections as an optional parameter. This way in my code I do not always have to add sections filter to my query. How can I make sections a nullable list in my function params but also work with Dapper when NULL?

**Here is my code:**

```
public static IEnumerable<Product> GetProformaFormularies(int? categoryId = null, IEnumerable<int> sections = null)
{
    using (var context = new AppContext())
    {
        var sql =
        "SELECT * " +
        "FROM Products " +
        "WHERE (@CategoryId IS NULL OR CategoryId = @CategoryId) " +
          "AND (Section IN @Sections)";

        return context.Database.Connection.Query<Product>(sql, 
        new { 
                CategoryId = categoryId,
                Sections = sections
            }).ToList();
    }
}
```

The only solution that I came up with is using Dynamic Parameters. Is there a better way than this?

```
var sql =
    "SELECT * " +
    "FROM ProformaFormulary " +
    "WHERE (@CategoryId IS NULL OR CategoryId = @CategoryId) " +

if (sections != null)
{
    sql += " AND (Section IN @Sections)";
}

var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("@CategoryId", categoryId);
if (sections != null)
{
    parameters.Add("@Sections", sections);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could just omit that portion of the `WHERE` clause if `sections` is `null`:

```
var sql =
    "SELECT * " +
    "FROM Products " +
    "WHERE (@CategoryId IS NULL OR CategoryId = @CategoryId) ";

if (sections != null)
{
    sql += "AND (Section IN @Sections)"
}

return context.Database.Connection.Query<Product>(sql, 
    new { 
            CategoryId = categoryId,
            Sections = sections
        }).ToList();
```

It looks like dapper will just ignore the `Sections` property on the object you're passing if it doesn't apply.

Comment: Unbelievable!!! Thank you so much. Check out the update I just made to my post with the solution that I just came up with. This one is much cleaner.

Comment: @MatthewPeterson: No problem! You solution is good too if you're bothered by passing the extra "Sections" property when it's not necessary

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion the if statement in code is not what you want sometimes. I sometimes just execute `.sql` files. So the only thing that worked for me is this.

```
var parameters = new
            {
                ApplySectionFilter = stringsToFilter != null,
                Sections = stringsToFilter 
            };
```

There is a bit overhead, but in the end, it's more clean. In my opinion.

```
SELECT * FROM Products
    WHERE (@ApplySectionFilter = 0 OR Section IN @Sections)
```